# Multiple assignments to a variable in javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to accomplish the below:

```
$rootscope.$on('function', var1, var2, var3){
var renderObejcts = $('.launch').fullGrid({
   events: function(zone1, zone2, callback) 
           { 
               //some $http.get callfor events type 1
               events = $http.get().then(
               ....
               callback(events);
                )
              
           },
  //here I need an appending kind of assignment to events of type2. 
});
}
```

The script which renders the events is expecting values to be under events. If I am using a separate variable event2, it is very hectic task to accomplish. I just want event type2 to be appending to existing. If I am using the second http call in above success block, this is going to async and events are not rendering properly, async and await functions are of no use. Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If what I understand is right

```
$rootscope.$on('function', var1, var2, var3){
var renderObejcts = $('.launch').fullGrid({
    events: function(zone1, zone2, callback){ 
      events = $http.get()
      events2 = $http.get()
      $q.all([events, events2]).then(function(ev1, ev2){
            // callback logic...
      })       
   } 
});
}
```

OR if you want to add an event type

```
$rootscope.$on('function', var1, var2, var3){
var eventObj = {
   events: function(zone1, zone2, callback){ 
      $http.get().then(
          ....
          eventObj['event2'] = function() { ... }
      )
              
   }
}
var renderObejcts = $('.launch').fullGrid(eventObj);
}
```